# Regex to find ONLY a particular string between a string and parantheses

Tags: powershell, regex

I'm trying to replace the string "Business Service Management" (without the quotes) which comes between "Assigned Workgroup" and ')'. For example:

> project in (KISHORE_TEST, "Business Service Management") AND "Assigned Workgroup" in (KISHORE_TEST,"Business Service Management", "Account","BSM Automation") OR "Workgroup" in ("BSM Automation") OR "Assigned Workgroup" in ("Business Service Management","BSM Automation") OR "Assigned Workgroup" in ("BSM Automation") and team = "Business Service Management"

The regex should match ONLY:

1. "Assigned Workgroup" in (KISHORE_TEST,"Business Service Management", "Account","BSM Automation")
2. "Assigned Workgroup" in ("Business Service Management","BSM Automation")

All other occurrences of "Business Service Management" which are not between the mentioned pattern should be omitted.

I just came up with `(?<=Assigned Workgroup)(.*?)(\w*Business Service Management*\w)(.*?)\)` which i know is wrong but I'm new to regex so unable to come up with the correct one.

May i request your help here?

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: Hello.I'm using powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one does the job:

```
Assigned Workgroup.*?"\KBusiness Service Management(?="[^)]*\))
```

**Explanation:**

```
Assigned Workgroup              : literally
.*?                             : 0 or more any character, not greedy
"                               : a double quote
\K                              : forget all we have seen until this position
Business Service Management     : literally
(?=                             : positive lookahead
  "                             : a double quote
  [^)]*                         : 0 or more anyy character that is not a close parenthesis
  \)                            : a close parenthesis
)                               : end lookahead
```

**Usage:**

Using perl

```
my $str = <<EOD;
project in (KISHORE_TEST, "Business Service Management") AND "Assigned Workgroup" in (KISHORE_TEST,"Business Service Management", "Account","BSM Automation") OR "Workgroup" in ("BSM Automation") OR "Assigned Workgroup" in ("Business Service Management","BSM Automation") OR "Assigned Workgroup" in ("BSM Automation") and team = "Business Service Management"
EOD

$str =~ s/Assigned Workgroup.*?"\KBusiness Service Management(?="[^)]*\))/new_string/g;
say $str;
```

**Output:**

> project in (KISHORE_TEST, "Business Service Management") AND "Assigned Workgroup" in (KISHORE_TEST,"new_string", "Account","BSM Automation") OR "Workgroup" in ("BSM Automation") OR "Assigned Workgroup" in ("new_string","BSM Automation") OR "Assigned Workgroup" in ("BSM Automation") and team = "Business Service Management"

This will work with php and with Notepad++ and many language/tool that use PCRE regex flavour.

---

If you have some difficulties with lookaround, you could use:

- Find: `(Assigned Workgroup.*?")Business Service Management("[^)]*\))`
- Replace: `$1new_string$2`

Comment: WOW! AWESOME! This works perfect on https://regex101.com/ but when i try the same regex on powershell, it is throwing an error "Regular expression pattern is invalid".

Comment: @KishoreSrinivasan: Well, I don't know how does powershell deal with regex. May be it doesn't understand `\K`, you could try with `(?<=Assigned Workgroup.*?")` instead of `Assigned Workgroup.*?"\K`

Comment: Using (Assigned Workgroup.*?")Business Service Management("[^)]*\)) and Replacing with $1new_string$2 did the trick! The approach is simply superb! Thanks a ton for your time and explanation! Magical!

Comment: @KishoreSrinivasan The [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) do work in PowerShell `$Text -Replace '(?<=Assigned Workgroup.*?")Business Service Management(?="[^)]*\))','new_string'` The \K does not, nice job +1

Answer (score 0):

This will not be the best solution, but you might want to try out this

`(?<="Assigned Workgroup" in \()["?\w"?|,]*\"(Business Service Management)`

which you can contiunue to refine at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/1jNdZP/1). You then need to use `\1` or `$1` to reference the capture group that contains *Business Service Management* in order to replace it.

Comment: You are welcome, this site helped me a lot of times to get what I want or to optimize the amount of cicles needed to achive my aim. Take a look at [johndcook](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/powershell_perl_regex/) for Powershell vs. Perl in regard of regex.

Comment: I found out, that Powershell uses the .NET library to perform RegEx operations. The library is not aware of the `\K' option. You need to achieve it a different manner without '\K'. You can try out .NET RegEx at [REGEX STORM](http://regexstorm.net/tester). Maybe I have time to look at this problem later this day.

Comment: Try this `(?<="Assigned Workgroup" in \(["?\w"?|,]*\")(Business Service Management)`

Comment: Kevin - This throws a pattern error but definitely something that can be fixed if spent some time. Thank you very much for your help and pointing me in the right direction! The regex provided by Toto helped in achieving what i was looking for.